# How to convert a TZ Datetime to Timestamp(3) in Flink SQL

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

How do you convert a DateTime with the `TZ` to Timestamp(3) in Flink SQL v1.13?

```
TO_TIMESTAMP('2021-12-16T20:29:37Z', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') //returns NULL
```

```
TO_TIMESTAMP('2021-12-16 20:29:37', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') //returns 2021-12-16T20:29:37
```

```
TO_TIMESTAMP('2021-12-16T20:29:37', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') //returns NULL, which is silly because this was the result from the 2nd example
```

It does not accept the `T and Z`, however the conversion result for a "clean" date has the `T`. But if I try the reverse operation, it returns null.

Answer (score 1):

Flink knows two representations of timestamps in string format: `SQL` and `ISO-8601`.

The SQL one follows `2021-12-16 20:29:37` and is accepted by `TO_TIMESTAMP`. It is also the result of a `CAST(ts AS STRING)`.

The ISO-8601 follows `2021-12-16T20:29:37` and might be accepted by future built-in utility functions.

The questions is: How do you "leave the SQL world" by printing? If you stay in the table ecosystem and call `table.execute().print()` future Flink versions will print the SQL format. Also the SQL Client will do this. At least this will be the behavior in Flink 1.15 and might already be the case in Flink 1.14.

If you do `table.execute().collect().forEach(println)` you print "via the Java world" which means that `java.time.LocalDateTime.toString` is called which uses ISO-8601 format.